# Does pathos.multiprocessing have starmap?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pathos

I got an error when executing code below. The problem seems to be `map` doesn't support functions taking multiple inputs, just as in the python built-in `multiprocessing` package. But in the built-in package, there is a `starmap` that solves this issue. Does `pathos.multiprocessing` have the same?

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp


class Bar:
    def foo(self, name):
        return len(str(name))

    def boo(self, x, y, z):
        sum = self.foo(x)
        sum += self.foo(y)
        sum += self.foo(z)
        return sum


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Bar()
    pool = mp.ProcessingPool()
    results = pool.map(b.boo, [(12, 3, 456), (8, 9, 10), ('a', 'b', 'cde')])
    print(results)
```

> TypeError: boo() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'

**Update for lambda expression as suggested (didn't work):**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Bar()
    pool = mp.ProcessingPool()
    results = pool.map(lambda x: b.boo(*x), [(12, 3, 456), (8, 9, 10), ('a', 'b', 'cde')])
    print(results)
```

> multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback:
>
> """
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\yg451\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py",
>   line 121, in worker
>
> result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\yg451\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py",
>   line 44, in mapstar
>
> return list(map(*args))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\yg451\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pathos\helpers\mp_helper.py",
>   line 15, in
>
> func = lambda args: f(*args)
>
> File "C:/Users/yg451/Code/foo/Machine
>   Learning/xPype/test/scratch.py", line 18, in
>
> results = pool.map(lambda x: b.boo(*x), [(12, 3, 456), (8, 9, 10), ('a', 'b', 'cde')])
>
> NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>
> """

Comment: Why don't you just make your function accept a tuple?

Comment: Or use `lambda x: b.boo(*x)`?

Comment: hmm, don't most functions accept multiple parameters instead of tuple, kinda ugly to make all functions potentially being paralleled take a tuple. As of the lambda expression solution, I tried, `...pool.map(lambda x: b.boo(*x), ...`, it didn't work, seems python `multipleprocessing` doesn't work on lambda expression at all

Comment: How did it not work? Internally, there's no difference between a lambda and a regular function, so I'm having trouble believing that.

Comment: trust me, I believe you have trouble believing that as I used to have trouble believing that (or I have simply been doing it wrong). I will update to show what I tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: That looks like a scoping error. The authoritative answer fixed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author. `pathos` is older than `starmap`, and doesn't really need it.  It solved multiple arguments in a pool exactly the same way that the built-in `map` does.

```
>>> import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
>>> class Bar:
...     def foo(self, name):
...         return len(str(name))
...     def boo(self, x, y, z):
...         sum = self.foo(x)
...         sum += self.foo(y)
...         sum += self.foo(z)
...         return sum
... 
>>> b = Bar()
>>> pool = mp.ProcessingPool()
>>> f = lambda x: b.boo(*x)    
>>> results = pool.map(f, [(12, 3, 456), (8, 9, 10), ('a', 'b', 'cde')])
>>> results 
[6, 4, 5]
>>> results = pool.map(b.boo, [12, 9, 'a'], [3, 9, 'b'], [456, 10, 'cde'])
>>> results
[6, 4, 5]
>>> results = map(b.boo, [12, 9, 'a'], [3, 9, 'b'], [456, 10, 'cde'])
>>> list(results)
[6, 4, 5]
>>>
```

So, essentially, `starmap` is unnecessary.  However, as it's been recently added to the standard `Pool` interface in `multiprocessing` in certain versions of python, it probably should be more prominent in `pathos`.  Note that it already is possible to get to an "augmented" version of `starmap` from `pathos` if you like.

```
>>> import pathos
>>> mp = pathos.helpers.mp
>>> p = mp.Pool()
>>> p.starmap
<bound method Pool.starmap of <multiprocess.pool.Pool object at 0x1038684e0>>
>>>
```

Comment: It's awesome to get it from the horses mouth like that :)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! Could you elaborate on this "augmented" `starmap` you mentioned? I must be missing something, but isn't this `p` simply the built-in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, why wouldn't I need pathos to construct that?

Comment: Notice it's `multiprocess` not `multiprocessing`... so that indicates the `Pool` uses `dill` and not `pickle` for advanced serialization.

Comment: oh..., my bad! Thank you!

Comment: when I try this code I get `NameError: name 'b' is not defined` for `pool.map(f, [(12, 3, 456), (8, 9, 10), ('a', 'b', 'cde')])`, any clues what this might be about (I'm using Python 3.9)?

Comment: I just retried the code with python3.9 and it works for me. Feel free to fill out a GitHub issue for pathos. you can provide more information there, and we can figure out why you are seeing an error a bit more easily